# CSS flip card does not show backface relative children elements until the transition is complete

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Taking flip card example from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

```
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

If I make a simple change to one of the children elements of the back card to position it relative, I do not see any back card elements until the transform is complete.

```
<div class="flip-card-back">
  <h1 style="position: relative;">John Doe</h1>
  <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  <p>We love that guy</p>
</div>
```

[image]

In my scenario I am creating a flip card with 3rd party child elements and I cannot modify those elements relative position.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's a browser related problem. For me, Chrome and Firefox both open up the original code perfectly, but in Safari it is broken. After making the child's position relative, Chrome's behavior happens as you're describing, but Firefox still displays correctly.

Comment: For me chrome is broken.

Comment: weird. I think the example given by Shahryar Mohajer might have better browser support

Comment: Same problem with his answer, If I put any relative positioned children in his "back" div the same thing happens.

Comment: You're right, I just tested it. I get the same results with his code as yours.

Answer (score 0):

check this: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/jOEqyWY

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

examples:

https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: This does not help, your code exhibits the exact same problem.  If I put any relative content in the "back" div all child elements will not display until the flip transform is complete.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/eYmZdWN

your code work fine , probably another css class override your codes

Comment: Nope, you missed the main point of the question.  Change this       <h1 style="position: relative">John Doe</h1>.  IE if you have any relative positioned child in the back, the entire back will not show until after the transition.  Also only happens on the first flip, so make sure to reload your pen each time to see what is happening.

Comment: changed it but it's working as before! 

codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/eYmZdWN

Comment: Probably browser dependent.  Works in FF for me but not chrome on my Mac.  If you cannot reproduce cool, but your answer doesn't fix the problem.  In addition, your answer does not work at all in Safari.

Comment: it works fine in windows chrome too but you can adjust that with -webkit-transform

Comment: Tried on windows and mac, and I see the same problem.  Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/jOEqyWY check this , back-title and back are position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

### Check [Dylan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6798006/dylan-anlezark) answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379794/card-back-hidden-on-first-transition-in-chrome)

I have tested this on a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rumbletumble/pen/abzJWyb) given your example, which appears to work.

It seems that if you add

- `transform-style: preserve-3d`

to the card back, then this will not present the issue.  I can only assume that this is a bug in Chrome, as the issue doesn't appear to present itself in Firefox or Safari ( I haven't tested in edge )