# Card back hidden on first transition in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, css-transitions

I'm developing a generic card that displays various content on the front and back.  The card flips 180 degrees on a click.

In Chrome, when I have content on the back that contains absolute or relative positioning, the back of the card only becomes visible at (or near) the end of the transition.

In Safari and Firefox I don't see the same issue.

The issue can be seen in this pen
https://codepen.io/rumbletumble/pen/GRgNeLg

I've tried

- Using animation rather than transition, but the same issue exists
- Adding `backface-visibility: visible` to the card back, but this causes flickering on the card

Could this simply be a bug in Chrome?

[image: Animation gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the below class and it now seems to be working fine across all browsers. (wan't able to test IE)

```
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: cornSilk;
  text-align: center;
  font: 3em/240px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work.  The issue only happens on the first transition, with subsequent transitions not presenting the issue.  backface-visibility appears to have been supported fully in Chrome for more than 5 years now, so vendor prefix should not be necessary. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility

Comment: Sorry I must of posted this before I truly finished editing, I have made an edit to the above and now seems to work for me and you are correct about back-face-visibility being supported for ages, should always go to the official docs duh!

Comment: It seems that adding transform-style: preserve-3d; to the back has fixed this.  However, I'm unsure why.  From what I read in the docs, this would create a new 3D context, but we already specified preserve-3d on the 'flipper' containing element.  Any idea why this solves the issue?

Comment: If you have any further links on it, that'd be great.  Thanks for your answer!