# CSS text isn't showing instantly after gradient is drawn

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird issue. This only happens on the initial card flip.

I have text that shows on top of a gradient background. This background image shows on mouse hover.

The text takes a split second to show and then it just pops in. I need the text to already be there when the image is flipped or at least have a smooth transition in if this isn't possible. I have traced it down to the placement of the text in different corners of the image. If I remove the css for the placement of the text then it shows and works fine.

Here is the Html

```
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img  [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:'+image.mimeType+';base64, '+image.frontImage)"  alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back linear-gradient">
      <h1 class="info">{{getTitle()}}</h1>
      <p class="info-bottom-right">{{getTitle()}}</p>
      <p class="info-bottom-left">{{getTitle()}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.info{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.info-bottom-right{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info-bottom-left{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is a stackblitz showing the actual issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyo4a8-sura86?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.css

Comment: I'm only getting the issue on chrome so it seems like a compatibility problem with one of the css rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a known bug with Chromium browsers - [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379794/card-back-hidden-on-first-transition-in-chrome) finally shed some light on it. All you have to do is add `preserve-3d` to the front and back classes.

```
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **transition : transform 0.8s;** applies also to the text so it adds a small delay to the text to appear when the cards flips. If you change it to 0.3s the card will flip faster but the text will also appear faster

Comment: So is there a middle ground here or Is it possible to fade the text in so it looks professional at least?

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem, it's just making it happen faster... This is part of the issue though I think. Removing the `position` attribute from the text elements fixes the issue so it may be related to how position is applied after transform.

Comment: Where to you get the Month from ?